# What is the best way to achieve Audio Video Synchronization in Android Based Media Player Application using MediaCodec API?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-mediacodec, stagefright

I'm trying to implement a Media Player in android using the `MediaCodec` API.

I've created three threads
Thread 1 : To de-queue the input buffers to get free indices and then queuing the `audio` and `video` frames in respective codec's input buffer

Thread 2 : To de-queue the `audio` codec's output buffer and render it using `AudioTrack` class' write method

Thread 3 : To de-queue the `video` codec's output buffer and render it using `releaseBuffer` method

I'm facing a lot of problem in achieving synchronization between `audio` and `video` frames. I never drop `audio` frames and before rendering `video` frames I check whether the decoded frames are late by more than 3omsecs, if they are I drop the frame, if they are more than 10ms early I don't render the frame.

To find the difference between `audio` and `video` I use following logic

```
public long calculateLateByUs(long timeUs) {
        long nowUs = 0;

        if (hasAudio && audioTrack != null) {
            synchronized (audioTrack) {
                if(first_audio_sample && startTimeUs >=0){
                    System.out.println("First video after audio Time Us: " + timeUs );
                    startTimeUs = -1;
                    first_audio_sample = false;
                }

            nowUs = (audioTrack.getPlaybackHeadPosition() * 1000000L) /
                    audioCodec.format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE);
        }

    } else if(!hasAudio){
        nowUs = System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000;
        startTimeUs = 0;

    }else{
        nowUs = System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000;

    }

    if (startTimeUs == -1) {
        startTimeUs = nowUs - timeUs;
    }
    if(syslog){
        System.out.println("Timing Statistics:");             
        System.out.println("Key Sample Rate :"+ audioCodec.format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE) +  " nowUs: " + nowUs + " startTimeUs: "+startTimeUs + " timeUs: "+timeUs + " return value :"+(nowUs - (startTimeUs + timeUs)));
    }

    return (nowUs - (startTimeUs + timeUs));
}
```

`timeUs` is the presentation time in micro-seconds of the video frame. `nowUs` is supposed to contain the duration in micro-seconds for which `audio` has been playing. `startTimeUs` is the initial difference between `audio` and `video` frames which has to be maintained always.

The first if block checks, if there is indeed an `audio` track and it has been initialized and sets the value of `nowUs` by calculating it from `audiotrack`
If there is **no** `audio` (first else) `nowUs` is set to `SystemTime` and the initial gap is set to zero. `startTimeUs` is initialized to zero in main function.

The if block in the synchronized block is used in case, first frame to be rendered is `audio` and `audio` frame joins later. `first_audio_sample` flag is initially set to true.

Please let me know if anything is not clear.

Also if you know of any open source link where media player of an a-v file has been implemented using video codec, that would be great.

Comment: @MayureshG.. Did my response help you or do you still have any open questions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on one of the latest releases of `Android`, you can consider retrieving the `audioTimeStamp` from `AudioTrack` directly. Please refer to this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#getTimestamp%28android.media.AudioTimestamp%29) for more details. Similarly, you could also consider retrieving the `sampling rate` via [`getSampleRate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#getSampleRate%28%29).

If you wish to continue with your algorithm, you could consider a relatively similar implementation in this native example. `SimplePlayer` implements a player engine by employing `MediaCodec` and has an *a-v sync* section too. Please refer to this [section of code](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/cmds/stagefright/SimplePlayer.cpp#516) where the synchronization is performed. I feel this should help as a good reference.